# What is the equivalent Glue Spark configuration to use SageMaker processing?

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to migrate Glue custom PySpark jobs to SageMaker processing to benefit from MLOps provided by SageMaker Pipeline.

1. In Glue, my job uses 10 G.1X (4 CPUs, 16G memory) instances and completed in 10min.
2. I tried to use similar SageMaker processing instances (10 ml.m5.xlarge instances with 4 CPUs, 16G memory for each), but failed because OOM *"OutOfMemoryError: Please use an instance type with more memory, or ensure that your processing container does not use more memory than available."*  When I checked the cloudwatch instance metrics, the maximum memory usage across all 10 instances are just 37.4%, so actually not used up all memory.

Glue doesn't expose `spark-submit` parameters (e.g., --conf spark.executor.memory) on their dashboard, so how can I check if my SageMaker processing job uses the same config as the Glue jobs, and what is the best practice to keep their spark configuration to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific component that allows you to do [Data Processing with Apache Spark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/use-spark-processing-container.html) in Amazon SageMaker.

It is called [PySparkProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html#pysparkprocessor).

It works like any other Processing Job. You can also, of course, specify your [run args](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.spark.processing.PySparkProcessor.get_run_args).

---

An example for specify memory config:

```py
from sagemaker.spark.processing import PySparkProcessor

spark_processor = PySparkProcessor(
    base_job_name="spark-preprocessor",
    framework_version="2.4",
    role=role,
    instance_count=2,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    max_runtime_in_seconds=1200,
)

configuration=[
    {
        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
        "Properties": {
            "spark.driver.memory": "4g"
       },
   }
]

spark_processor.run(
    submit_app="preprocess.py",
    arguments=['s3_input_bucket', bucket,
               's3_input_key_prefix', input_prefix,
               's3_output_bucket', bucket,
               's3_output_key_prefix', output_prefix],
    configuration = configuration
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use the PySparkProcessor.  It is the one that didn't keep similar performance compare to my Glue job.  I'm looking for what exactly the Glue provided for the "Properties".

Comment: In its [_SparkProcessorBase](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/7268e82d45b522424891ddd8267ad00ef0cffd23/src/sagemaker/spark/processing.py#L44) class there are all configurations used by PySparkProcessor. It exists also a private method called [_extend_processing_args()](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/7268e82d45b522424891ddd8267ad00ef0cffd23/src/sagemaker/spark/processing.py#L779) useful to watch

Comment: I know I can set config to PysparkProcessor, but I'm looking for copying the config from AWS Glue to the PysparkProcessor.  Do you by chance know how AWS Glue config the Spark jobs?

Comment: When you create a job on Glue, you can see the autogenerated Spark code. You could start there and investigate line by line.
You can find [examples of ETL](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples) code and a [step-by-step explanation of an AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html). I would try to follow the Glue-generated code from one of those examples and reproduce it in your PySparkProcessor, so you can verify that you get the same performance.

Comment: Not exactly what I mean.  I do not have trouble replicate the PySpark code from glue to Sagemaker processing.  But I have trouble in replicate Spark CONFIGURATION (e.g., `--spark.executor.memory`, `--spark.executor.memoryOverhead`, and tens of others).  I want to make sure Sagemaker processing using the exact same set of Spark configuration as Glue does.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the PySpark Glue config with this piece of code :

```
configurations = spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
for item in configurations: print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know if it prints what I'm looking for.